# How to display folder and current branch on a single line on GIT?

Tags: git

I would like a command to display folder and current branch **on the same line with color for the branch name**, i.e. `<my_git_folder> (master)` ideally with `(master)` in green

The idea behind all of this is to use an `all` alias to parse all subfolders and start the display for each subfolder by `<my_git_folder> (master)` for all git commands, e.g. `git all branch`, `git all status --short`, etc.. and get an output like this:

```
> git all status --short
GIT_folder1_name (master)
M toto.c
D dummy.h

GIT_folder2_name (debug)
M tata.c
D dymmu.h
...
```

For the moment, I use a mix of `git status -bsuno` and following `all` alias (deeply inspired from others topics on stackoverflow ;-):

```
all = "!f() { ls -R --directory --color=never */.git 
              | xargs -i sh -c 
                  \" git -C {}/.. rev-parse --show-toplevel | xargs basename 
                  && git -C {}/.. $1 \" ; 
            }; f"
```

and get an output like this:

```
> git all status -bsuno
GIT_folder1_name
## master
M toto.c
D dummy.h

GIT_folder2_name
## debug
M tata.c
D dymmu.h
...
```